# Impedance of PCB track

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, impedance, inductance

I was wondering if PCB tracks have a typical complex impedance?

This is for a signal of frequency 1khz.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It's very unusual to need controlled impedance at 1 kHz.

Comment: This is very application specific. It depends on trace width, substrate material, distance between signal and ground layers, etc.

Comment: Signal frequency is not the value considered when determining whether or not controlled impedance is necessary. The slew rate is much more crucial and is pretty much the sole cause of EMI issues in a design. In general it is safe to route just about any digital signal with a 50 ohm impedance (single-ended) or 100 ohm (differential), unless the transmitter and receiver specify a different value

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do have impedance. The value will depend on many parameters that you have not supplied: copper thickness, spacing to other conductors on every layer, substrate material, trace length, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

When the signal bandwidth is much lower than the wavelength of the trace, you only consider the lumped element trace resistance, inductance and capacitance per unit length.  Then if it is high impedance, then consider crosstalk from current high mutual coupling impedance by L or C to noise sources.

C depends on coupling to nearby-ground plane typ. 0.3pF/cm if very close gap < trace width. L is about 8 nH/cm but can be looked up using Saturn PCB Design tool.

Comment: Wont these numbers depend a lot on tracewidth ?

Comment: Yes @tobalt but not as much as length . L might vary 20% in most choices, C depends on area/gap ratio of dielectric.